# Save vimdiff output?

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I google'd this multiple times in the past but I've never found an answer. Is there a way to save vimdiff's output (preferably while maintaining colors, highlights, etc.)? I'd like to send this one output file to other people and tell them "just open this file, here are the differences, side by side and highlighted".

If there are better alternatives to vimdiff for this purpose, I'm open to suggestions - something that would work on both Windows and Linux platforms is ideal.

Comment: `diff -u` + editor with diff highliting?

Comment: See `:h :TOhtml`

Comment: @rvs: I'd like the diff to be side by side, with equivalent lines shown as dashes (or something similar), a la vimdiff.

Comment: @El Isra: I've run across TOhtml before but AFAIK it only outputs one buffer at a time. I'd like the diff (both buffers) to be in a single file. EDIT: nevermind! seems to work!

Comment: @El Isra: Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as such :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Vim can export to HTML, see:

```
:help :TOhtml
```

Answer (score 36):

To compare two files and write out the result to a third file "HTML based". Open a terminal and run this command:

```
vimdiff  file1.txt file2.txt -c TOhtml -c 'w! diff.html' -c 'qa!'
```

Answer (score 10):

You'll get similar output with the next command:

```
sdiff file1 file2 | colordiff
```

Comment: vim can do 4 files, sdiff is limited to 2

Comment: This was more useful for me than TOhtml since now the two files are nicely lined up and easy to process with a script.

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two options for saving vim colouring: it is `:TOhtml` distributed with vim itself and more advanced my [format.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3113) plugin. Advantages of my plugin over `:TOhtml` are described on the plugin page. Command to format vimdiff to html:

```
:Format diffformat
```

Answer (score 1):

```
diff -u file1 file2 > outputfile
```