# Unix diff side-by-side with context

Tags: linux, unix, diff, sdiff

In Unix, execute

```
diff -y file1 file2
```

can see two files side-by side. And execute

```
diff -c file1 file2
```

can see two files' difference with 3 line context.
Execute

```
diff -y --supress-common-lines
```

can suppress all the common lines. But what if I want to display side-by-side but with 3 lines context? `--supress-common-lines` will provide no context at all

```
diff -y -c file1 file2
```

will give me `conflicting output style options`. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Note that --supress-common-lines might only be available on most modern diffutils versions. For instance, on diffutils 3.3 (On CentOS 7.7) it is not included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `diff(1)` doesn't allow it, but [vimdiff](https://linux.die.net/man/1/vimdiff) seems to work:

```
vimdiff -c 'set diffopt=context:3' file1 file2
```

Downside is that it's interactive-only, you can't dump the diff to a file, but then again, side-by-side diffs are not very useful in files. However, if you do want to save it to a file, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47890981) awesome answer will have you do:

```
vimdiff -c 'set diffopt=context:3' -c TOhtml -c 'w! output.html' -c 'qa!' file1 file2
```

Not ideal, but it's something.

Comment: This is amazing, TOhtml command on vim, the rendered html looks exactly like the vim diff screen, same colours and fonts. Really good, thanks

Comment: what if you want to compare entire folder's content like you can with `diff` ?

Comment: I guess you'd [need a plugin](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/790).